# Get a particular string from an expression in a column in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in my SQL Server database table which contains '|' (pipe) separated values.

Example:

```
'FirstName |testname| lastName | lastname | roll |ee097765 | 100 | end'
'FirstName |testname1| lastName | lastname1 | roll2 |ee0977652 | 1100 | end'.
```

I want to extract the marks only using T-SQL, where my output column will have only marks i.e. 100 only or 1100 subsequently. In Oracle we can use the

```
    SUBSTRING_INDEX
```

function, but the same is not available in T-SQL.

Can anyone point me how to do this?

```
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, '|', 3), '|', -1)
```

Comment: This is going to be tough to do with just basic SQL Server code.  A better long term solution would be for you to _normalize_ your data and get each value into a separate column.  It will be very difficult for you to use your data in CSV format like this.

Comment: Your table design is defeating the whole purpose of having a RDBMS system... if you want to deal with comma (or pipe) separated values, you can just use a csv file.

Comment: I would suggest CLR function (using Regex or Split).

Comment: @Hooman its a 3rd party table we cannot change that so need a way out.. :(

Comment: @JohnyL Can u plz provide me a sample?

Comment: So, you need to get the index (position) of these markers or values themselves?

Comment: i need to get the value between the particular index i.e the varchar value between the 5th and 6th '|' pipe. Here it should return me ee0977652  for second case and ee097765  for first.

Comment: Have done the same by writing a function which get the index of the nth pipe and then use the SUBSTRING function to find the same. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @TEST table(val  nvarchar(1000))

insert into @TEST
values ('FirstName |testname| lastName | lastname | roll |ee097765 | 100 | end'),
        ('FirstName |testname1| lastName | lastname1 | roll2 |ee0977652 | 1100 | end')

 SELECT Value 
  FROM @TEST CROSS APPLY 
       Split(val,'|')
  WHERE ISNUMERIC(Value) = 1
```

You just have to use a generic split function you'll find : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15125/sql-server-split-function

Answer (score 0):

You could use SQLCLR function. There are some caveats in applying it to SQL Server. Anyway, here's one of the variants to find required values:

```
public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString GetMarkPosition(SqlString sqlString)
    {
        // Assume there will be no result,
        // so initialize return value to null string.
        SqlString retVal = SqlString.Null;

        // Extract C# string
        string input = sqlString.Value;

        // I use Regex Split method rather array Split method,
        // since Regexe method handles spaces in elegant way.
        string pattern = @"\s*\|\s*";

        // Get array of values
        string[] split = Regex.Split(input, pattern);

        // The logic is the following:
        // First, we find the marker's position in list.
        // The sought value is one index less.
        // This process is repeated for each marker.
        // If no match is found for any marker,
        // the function will just return empty string,
        // as we initialized retVal variable.
        foreach (string marker in new[] { "100", "1100" })
        {
            var list = new List<string>(split);
            int index = list.IndexOf(marker);
            if (index > 0)
            {
                retVal = new SqlString(list[index - 1]);
                break;
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

In order to create this function, there are several steps you need to do.
If you're using SQL Server 2017, the security model has been changed (read, for example [here](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/28/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-4-trusted-assemblies-the-disappointment/) and [here](https://joeydantoni.com/2017/04/19/sqlclr-in-sql-server-2017/)), so Visual Studio won't help you in creating assembly on SQL Server's side - you'll have to do it manually.